# Keycloak on K8s installation failure with `ERROR: relation "migration_model" does not exist at character 25`

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, keycloak, ovh

Following the sample at https://github.com/thomasdarimont/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/keycloakx/examples/postgresql, I'm trying to install Keycloak and Postrgresql with helm charts on OVH managed Kubernetes but the database initialisation fails.

Here are the logs on Postgresql pod:

```
2023-04-14 07:22:21.638 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-04-14 07:23:04.073 GMT [195] ERROR:  relation "migration_model" does not exist at character 25
2023-04-14 07:23:04.073 GMT [195] STATEMENT:  SELECT ID, VERSION FROM MIGRATION_MODEL ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC
2023-04-14 07:23:05.364 GMT [195] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist at character 22
2023-04-14 07:23:05.364 GMT [195] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
2023-04-14 07:23:06.423 GMT [210] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
2023-04-14 07:23:06.423 GMT [210] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2023-04-14 07:23:06.831 GMT [195] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist at character 22
2023-04-14 07:23:06.831 GMT [195] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
```

I've read somewhere that it could be related to a PVC issue, so I tried to force it, but no more luck.

Here is the script I run:

```bash
kubectl create namespace keycloak
kubectl apply -f keycloak-postgresql-pvc.yml
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm repo add codecentric https://codecentric.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update
helm install keycloak-db bitnami/postgresql -n keycloak --values ./keycloak-postgresql-properties.yaml
helm install keycloak codecentric/keycloakx -n keycloak -f keycloak-install-properties.yml
kubectl apply -f ingress-nginx.yaml
```

and here are the files referenced:

- `keycloak-postgresql-pvc.yml`

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgresql-keycloak
  namespace: keycloak
  labels:
    app: postgresql
spec:
  storageClassName: csi-cinder-classic
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

- `keycloak-postgresql-properties.yaml`:

```yaml
# See https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql

global:
  postgresql:
    auth:
      username: keycloak
      password: change-me
      database: keycloak
primary:
  persistence:
    existingClaim: postgresql-keycloak
```

- `keycloak-install-properties.yml`

```yaml
# See https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration
# See https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config
image:
  tag: 21.0.2

command:
  - "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"
  - "--verbose"
  - "start"
  - "--auto-build"
  - "--http-enabled=true"
  - "--http-port=8080"
  - "--hostname-strict=false"
  - "--hostname-strict-https=false"
  - "--spi-events-listener-jboss-logging-success-level=info"
  - "--spi-events-listener-jboss-logging-error-level=warn"

extraEnv: |
  - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}-admin-creds
        key: user
  - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}-admin-creds
        key: password
  - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
    value: >-
      -XX:+UseContainerSupport
      -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0
      -Djava.awt.headless=true
      -Djgroups.dns.query={{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}-headless
dbchecker:
  enabled: true

database:
  vendor: postgres
  hostname: keycloak-db-postgresql
  port: 5432
  username: keycloak
  password: change-me
  database: keycloak

secrets:
  admin-creds:
    annotations:
      my-test-annotation: Test secret for {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}
    stringData:
      user: admin
      password: change-me

replicas: 1
restartPolicy: "Always"
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Anyone managed to install a recent Keycloak instance (note I'm using `codecentric/keycloakx` and not `codecentric/keycloak`) on OVH managed Kubernetes (with a DB on a PV)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the SQL errors during init are just some noise and the server was actually correctly installed. My issue was in the ingress rules to access it.

##### How did I figure that out?

I temporarily exposed the DB and explored it with my favorite DB admin tool (I already have a local Postgres bound to 5432, so using 5431):

```bash
kubectl get all -n keycloak
kubectl port-forward --namespace keycloak service/keycloak-db-postgresql 5431:5432
```

The DB at `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/keycloak` was there and correctly initialized.

I then did the same for the Keycloak server:

```bash
kubectl port-forward --namespace keycloak service/keycloak-keycloakx-http 8080:80
```

The server was up and running and accessible from: `http://localhost:8080`

##### Ingress for `codecentric/keycloakx`

When switching from `codecentric/keycloak` to `codecentric/keycloakx`, be aware that ports change from `8080` to `80` and `8443` to `443`. Also, the service name changes from `keycloak-http` to `keycloak-keycloakx-http`. So if you picked a sample ingress rule for the older chart, you have to adapt it. Here is what I used:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # This annotation indicates the issuer to use
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
  name: keycloak
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  rules:
  - host: change-me.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak-keycloakx-http
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - change-me.com
      secretName: keycloak-tls
```